# How to remove duplicated values in csv files

Tags: python, list, csv, tableau-api

My sample input file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPITB.png)

I want to remove this column name and print as row column names.so ,my output look like below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GnaHO.png)

Request you to help

Comment: Does the input file have multiple columns? If not, it's not really a CSV file and you can just read the files line by line into a set. If not we need to know what you want to do with the other columns

Comment: is this relevant to Tableau? please explain

Comment: Yes @MKD....I am extracting data from each view in dashboard using populate_csv method available in Tableau Server client.If Measure values(Aggregation valu- sum()) that will come as rows.In my report it was showed as seperate column.So my reports has 14 columns(4 columns - Measure value),but my extracted data has 2 columns(under measure names and measure amoutn it will come).So i trying to extract the data as what shown in report

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can start by using `pandas.DataFrame.pivot()` https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html

Comment: My third party policy doesnt allows us to install pandas and some other packages..I am trying to default packages in python (csv reader)